# Spring4Shell spring-boot-starter-webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have seen that one of the requirements for the vulnerability is to have either "spring-webmvc" or "spring-webflux" dependencies, but what about "spring-boot-starter-webflux"?

I can't find anything online that indicates that it is also affected, but I am also not too familiar with the dependency itself.

Comment: Please check [Am I Impacted? in spring article](https://spring.io/blog/2022/03/31/spring-framework-rce-early-announcement#am-i-impacted)

Comment: @samabcde I have looked at many lists like that. All of them say "spring-webflux". My question is if "spring-boot-starter-webflux" might also be vulnerable

Comment: spring-boot-starter-webflux has a transitive dependency to spring-webflux